# jQuery hasClass not working or flawed if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im working on a battleship game. The current genShips function should check if the div with coorinate x:y and its surroindings are already marked. If they are marked, then try with new x and y, if they aren't marked, aka there are no ships near, then place a ship on x:y, x+1:y. The ships are always 1x2 and horizontal. Corners can touch, but sides cant.

Heres the full code on http://jsfiddle.net/u43703ms/1/

and just the function itself.

```
function genShips() {
var gridLength = $("#option").val();
while (true) {
    var y = Math.floor(((Math.random() * gridLength)));
    var x = Math.floor(((Math.random() * gridLength)));
    var x2 = x + 1;
    $("#info").html(x + ":" + y);

    if 
    (
    $("#grid .cell[data-x="+x+"][data-y="+y+"]").hasClass("ship")
    || ($("#grid .cell[data-x="+x+"][data-y="+(y-1)+"]").hasClass("ship"))
    || ($("#grid .cell[data-x="+x+"][data-y="+(y+1)+"]").hasClass("ship"))
    || ($("#grid .cell[data-x="+(x-1)+"][data-y="+y+"]").hasClass("ship"))
    || ($("#grid .cell[data-x="+(x+1)+"][data-y="+y+"]").hasClass("ship"))
    || ($("#grid .cell[data-x="+(x2-1)+"][data-y="+y+"]").hasClass("ship")) 
    || ($("#grid .cell[data-x="+x2+"][data-y="+(y+1)+"]").hasClass("ship"))
    || ($("#grid .cell[data-x="+x2+"][data-y="+(y-1)+"]").hasClass("ship"))
    || ($("#grid .cell[data-x="+(x2+1)+"][data-y="+y+"]").hasClass("ship"))
    ) 

    {
        console.log("dont print ship");
    }
    else {
        console.log("print ship");
        $("#grid .cell[data-x="+x+"][data-y="+y+"]").attr("class", "ship");
        $("#grid .cell[data-x="+x2+"][data-y="+y+"]").attr("class", "ship");
        break;
    }

}
```

}

Generate gives you the desired gridsize(choose from dropdown menu) and genShips tries to put a ship on the grid. Right now it just doesn't see the "ship" class on the divs for some reason or my if statement is flawed.

And to better explain my if statement, it basically controls if theres a "ship" on x;y, up, down, left, right, and up down and right for the x2, the 2nd box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:-

```
.attr("class", "ship");
```

to:-

```
.addClass("ship");
```

in your full code

```
function klikk(x, y) {
    $(".cell").click(function() {
        $(this).attr("class", "ship");
    });
}
```

`.attr("class", "ship");` is replacing all the classes (`.cell`) leaving only `.ship`. so your `.cell` `hasClass` `.ship` will never be found.

Comment: @villur to that end, you could also remove the ".cell" in $("#grid .cell[data-x="+x+"][data-y="+(y-1)+"]").hasClass("ship")) e.g. $("#grid [data-x="+x+"][data-y="+(y-1)+"]").hasClass("ship")) then you don't need to factor in that class reducing meta info.

Comment: ohmygod, thank you for pointing this out!!!
will try to get this working tomorrow and post if I got it working, but I think this pretty much is the reason :)

Comment: This worked. And im using Seabizkits method atm. Thank you guys for pointing this out! :)

Answer (score 0):

I been staring at the code trying to work through what you trying to achieve. I think its pretty neat/cool. ;-)

I think you are wanting **&&** instead of **||**

haven't gone further to check if the logic would be correct with && but || doesn't seem to gel with me.

Try using **addClass** and **removeClass** instead of *Attr(class,"someclass")* as the latter removes any other class as well which may not be the intention.